# Reading a local Windows file in apache Spark

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use spark locally. My env is

1. Eclipse Luna with prebuild scala support.
2. Created a project and converted to maven and added Spark core depenedency Jar.
3. Downloaded WinUtils.exe and set HADOOP_HOME path.

The code i am trying to run is

```
object HelloWorld {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
          println("Hello, world!")
    /*      val master = args.length match {
            case x: Int if x > 0 => args(0)
            case _ => "local"
          }*/
          /*val sc = new SparkContext(master, "BasicMap", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))*/
          val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HelloWorld").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
          val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
         val input =  sc.textFile("C://Users//user name//Downloads//error.txt")
    // Split it up into words.
    val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    // Transform into pairs and count.
    val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
          counts.foreach(println)
```

But when i am using sparkContext to read file, it fails with below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/Downloads/error.txt
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:289)
at com.examples.HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:23)
at com.examples.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
```

Can someone provide me insight on how to overcome this error?

Comment: Do you have cygwin on your path?

Comment: @user52045 no I don't have cygwin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need it.

Comment: I have searched in net and many have adviced to desist installing cygwin for spark.instead they have asked to use winutils.exe.

Comment: Btw You have bad slashes in file path. If you use linux slashes you one. You only need to escape windows once.

Comment: This error does not looks like the problem with configuration. This just looks like there is no such file with this name. I wonder the standard windows catalog structure is C:/User/{User Name}/Downloads not C:User/Downloads?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the username is having space which was creating all problems. Once I moved to filepath with no spaces it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me on w10
with spark 2
as
in the sparksession.builder()
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///”)

and the using the \ in the path...

ps be sure to put the full extension of the files

[local] [file] [spark2]